# Search in select tag (without jquery and datalist)

Tags: javascript, select, search

I need to search on select tag options.
I tried datalist it works but in input when I choose option goes value of option and I don't need that, with select there is no such problems.
Also tried jquery chosen and select2 didn't work for me, maybe because I use angular and it overwrites something.
Tried angular material with its mat-form-field does not work.
Hope someone could help.
Here's my code

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm"
              [(ngModel)]="filters.userId">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option *ngFor="let user of users"
                [value]="user.id">

          <!--{{ user._profile?.lastName }}-->
          <!--{{ user._profile?.firstName }}-->
          <!--{{ user._profile?.fatherName }}-->

          {{ user.fullName }}

        </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The select field does not offer the option, to do a filter search trough it's items. Since you use angular, you can write your own component for this.